# Coldfusion Problem with decrypting: Unsupported parameter: javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec

Tags: java, coldfusion

I'm trying to decrypt a message using java objects through Coldfusion 2021.

First I created a java class which works totally fine, and added the jar to the javaPath setting of coldfusion, but it didnt work. So I tried to replicate the code in coldfusion, still using java objects. The code is bellow.

```
remote function decode () {

    var req_data = getHttpRequestData();

    var base64Decoder = createObject('java', 'java.util.Base64');
    var arrUtils = createObject('java', 'org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils');
    var keySpecInstance = createObject('java', 'javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec');
    var cipherInstance = createObject('java', 'javax.crypto.Cipher');
    var ivSpecInstance = createObject('java', 'javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec');

    var key = 'KEY_HERE';
    var iv = req_data.headers['x-initialization-vector'];
    var authTag = req_data.headers['x-authentication-tag'];
    var msg = req_data.content;

    key = base64Decoder.getDecoder().decode(key);
    var keySpec = keySpecInstance.init(key, 0, 32, 'AES');

    iv = base64Decoder.getDecoder().decode(iv);
    authTag = base64Decoder.getDecoder().decode(authTag);
    msg = base64Decoder.getDecoder().decode(msg);
    var cipherText = arrUtils.addAll(msg, authTag);

    var cipher = cipherInstance.getInstance('AES/GCM/NoPadding');
    cipher.init(cipherInstance.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpecInstance.init(iv));
    
    var msgBytes = cypher.doFinal(cipherText);

    writeDUmp(msgBytes);


}
```

Everything seems to be working but Coldfusion throws an error `Unsupported parameter: javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec@3a848c55` on the line `cipher.init(...)`

I've tried searching about this online but with no luck.

If someone has some insight on how to fix this, or at least clarify what does the error means I'd appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you check if `iv` value is correctly formatted as Base64?